# custom date format parse

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have some date returned from FTP server like this

```
Aug 28 11:03
Aug 28 18:06
Sep  6 16:03
```

Im using this code to parse the time

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
_fileDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestring, "MMM dd H:mm", provider);
```

The first two date work, but the last won't. Does any one have better ideas in parsing these kind of date format?

`MMM d H:mm` will work with `Sep 6 16:03` but in my case its `Sep   6 16:03` will not work, note the double space between Sep and 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **multiple issues**, one is which is already pointed out in other answers i.e. using single `d` for date since last date is `6` not `06`. The other problem with the last date is that it has **multiple spaces in between date and month** because of that your format which is taking care of dates with single space is not working. You need to first remove the extra space and then parse using format with single `d`. Try the following code:

```
    string timestring = "Sep  6 16:03";
   //string[] array = timestring.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   //timestring = string.Join(" ", array);
    timestring = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(timestring, @"\s+", " ");

    CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    DateTime _fileDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestring, "MMM d H:mm", provider);
```

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu, you are welcome, also update the code with a much better approach to remove extra spaces from the string

Answer (score 4):

> The first two date work, but the last won't.

That's because you are using `dd` for date and the last date returned is 6 and not 06. Use Single `d`. If last date returned was 06 your format would have worked like a charm.

Its should be like

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timestring, "MMM d H:mm", provider);
```

Comment: Sep 6 13:06 will work but Sep  6 13:06 wont wot=rk, Note that double space between Sep and 6

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu, that is the exact issue, pointed out in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12311697/961113)

Answer (score 2):

Use one `d` so it expects possible [single-digit days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier) (ie, "6" instead of "06").

```
MMM d H:mm
```